# Firebase multi location update, delete redundant data as part of update

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase multi location updates to update a number of locations in my database.

One of the update paths contains a value that could be changed as part of the update therefore creating a new record at the new path location which is correct. This then leaves a redundant data at the original location that I need to delete as part of the update. Can someone give me a pointer on how to delete the redundant data as part of the update?

I am using the code below to create my update: -

```
var updatedUserDataContent = {
    title: $scope.postToUpdate.title
    commenter: $scope.postToUpdate.commenter
};

updatedUserData["Posts/" + $scope.postToUpdate.$id] = updatedUserDataContent;

updatedUserData["UserPosts/" + $scope.postToUpdate.commenter + "/"   + $scope.postToUpdate.$id] = updatedUserDataContent;
```

The `commenter` could be changed by a user on the record before saving leaving the redundant data in the original `commenter` node. I have tried using the security rules but these stop data being created rather than deleted.

**Edit 1**

JSON as requested. 
Before the update I have

```
{
  "Not assigned" : {
"-KNfs3OhBmbb93w9VEW-" : {
  "title": "vytg",
  "commenter":  "Not assigned"
   }
  }
 }
```

After the update (after changing `commenter` from "Not assigned" to "User A") I have

```
{
  "Not assigned": {
"-KNfs3OhBmbb93w9VEW-": {
  "title": "vytg",
  "commenter": "Not assigned"
}
  },
"User A" : {
"-KNfs3OhBmbb93w9VEW-" : {
  "title": "vytg",
  "commenter":  "User A"
}
  }
 }
```

but I want just

```
{
"User A" : {
"-KNfs3OhBmbb93w9VEW-" : {
  "title": "vytg",
  "commenter":  "User A"
}
  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you show the minimal JSON (as text, no screenshots please) that you have before the update and that you want after the update?

Comment: JSON now in original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to move/rename a node, which is not an operation the database supports.

Since the new data is written correctly, all that is needed is that you also clear out the old node. Putting `null` in for that location will take care of that:

```
updatedUserData["Not assigned"] = null;
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, makes sense. The issue I now have is getting the original value of `$scope.postToUpdate.commenter` so that I can use it in the path to set it to `null`. I am using angularJS and thought angular.copy would be the way to go but cant get it to work. I guess that is another StackOverflow question!

Comment: Ok, managed to do this by using angular.copy to store the original commenter. Thanks for your help